# how to keep data in page after reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I have a page which loads a login page, after the user logged in it will load some parts of another file into itself. The problem is that I want to know which button is pressed in the first page and have it in the login page. The first page loads login page using `location.window` and it refreshes the page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: use ajax........`(..)`

Comment: I can not use ajax for this first page but all other pages is ajaxed and i have no problem with them. i saw some pages that we can attach data to window by ___events___ with jquery 1.4+ and tried that with nothing in results

Comment: 'which button' ? what are the buttons on the first page before the login page

Comment: the buttons are for select different functionality after login for example you choose file confirm and after login you go to file confirmation part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, You can take advantage of cookies/HTML5 localStorage to keep track of the page url.

Comment: and what about ie8 and lower? iknow i can use $.data or data-something but after page reload they all will be gone

Comment: Alternatively, you can use cookies too, for all browsers and their versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FORM then you can send the button information in hidden field, like

```
<input type="hidden" name="track" value="but1">
```

or if you are using GET method, you can send the info by query string, like

```
http://domain/login.php?track=but1
```

Comment: hi sorry i'm just writing UI code not server side and the scripts are not php too. i wonder if i can attach a simple line of data to page itself

Comment: It is an UI related code, there are no server side language added, form hidden field and query string is related to UI only...

Comment: sorry i have no forms and the buttons are just simple li and anchores